# Mysql deployment script generated in EF Core 5.0 doesn't support DDL transaction rollback

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

We are using EF core 5.0 with pomelo mysql db provider. We generate an idempotent sql script to add migration using efcore migration commands. We noticed that the transactions are not rolled back if there are db connection or timeout errors.

How can we ensure the generated script is idempotent, since in the existing state it doesn't behave right.

Comment: Why does the script need to be idempotent? That doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: The idea of an idempotent script is to apply only new migrations using a migration state preserved in your DB. EF core supports this feature (see):
[idempotent sql script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a MySQL limitation, not a Pomelo issue.
MySQL does not honor transactions when it comes to DDL statements.

However, INSERT/UPDATE statements should be rolled back correctly.

So the only safe way to apply migrations is to first create a backup of your database and then to apply the migration script.
Should its execution fail, you restore the backup.

It's not pretty, but it works.